# Is it possible to upload to S3 directly from URL using POST?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know there is a way to upload to S3 directly from the web browser using POST without the files going to your backend server. But is there a way to do it from URL instead of web browser.

Example, upload a file that resides at http://example.com/dude.jpg directly to S3 using post. I mean I don't want to download the asset to my server then upload it to S3. I just want to make a POST request to S3 and it uploads it automatically.

Comment: Googlers: skip the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this article with some details. You will probably have to modify your buckets' security settings in some fashion to allow this type of interaction.

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

There will be some security issues on the client as well since you never want your keys publicly accessible

Comment: The document mostly talk about uploading from client's web browser.

Comment: Client browser just executes POST. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: the link is no longer available

Answer (score 42):

It sounds like you want S3 itself to download the file from a remote server where you only pass the URL of the resource to S3.

This is not currently supported by S3.

It needs an API client to actually transfer the content of the object to S3.

Comment: S3 is currently able to upload files directly from client web browser, why not from a server?

Comment: S3 can accept a file uploaded from a server, but the server must initiate the upload to S3 and transfer the contents (thus becoming a client of S3). S3 cannot initiate the transfer from a another web server given a URL. Your server will need to download the file from the URL and then upload it to S3.

Comment: would be nice if it could initiate it though. :) maybe in the future. imageshack calls this transloading.

Comment: This functionality is still not supported by s3 isn't it?

Comment: @Jerry no, but cloudinary has it

Comment: @KylePennell too bad cloudinary costs an arm and a leg.

Comment: @EricHammond is your comment still valid? what's its relation with pre-signed URLs?

Answer (score 4):

I thought I should share my code to achieve something similar. I was working on the backend but possibly could do something similar in frontend though be mindful about **AWS credentials** likely to be **exposed**.

For my purposes, I wanted to download a file from the external URL and then ultimately get back the URL form S3 of the uploaded file instead.

I also used [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) in order to get the uploadable format and [`file-type`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) to get the proper type of the file but that is not the requirement.

Below is the snippet of my code:

```
async function uploadAttachmentToS3(type, buffer) {
  var params = {
   //file name you can get from URL or in any other way, you could then pass it as parameter to the function for example if necessary
    Key : 'yourfolder/directory/filename', 
    Body : buffer,
    Bucket : BUCKET_NAME,
    ContentType : type,
    ACL: 'public-read' //becomes a public URL
  }
  //notice use of the upload function, not the putObject function
  return s3.upload(params).promise().then((response) => {
    return response.Location
  }, (err) => {
    return {type: 'error', err: err}
  })
}

async function downloadAttachment(url) {
  return axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  })
  .then(response => {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, 'base64');
    return (async () => {
      let type = (await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer)).mime
      return uploadAttachmentToS3(type, buffer)
    })();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return {type: 'error', err: err}
  });  
}

let myS3Url = await downloadAttachment(url)
```

I hope it helps people who still struggle with similar issues. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use rclone to achieve this easily:
https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_copyurl/

Create a new access key on AWS for rclone and use rclone config like this:
https://rclone.org/s3/

Then, you can easily interact with your S3 buckets using rclone.

To upload from URL:
`rclone -Pva copy {URL} RCLONE_CONFIG_NAME:/{BUCKET_NAME}/{FOLDER}/`

It is quite handy for me as I am archiving my old files from Dropbox Business to S3 Glacier Deep Archive to save on Dropbox costs.

I can easily create a file transfer from Dropbox (100GB per file limit), copy the download link and upload directly to S3 using rclone.

It is copying at 10-12 MiB/s on a small DigitalOcean droplet.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Just to be clear here the download happens to a local machine and then to the S3 bucket even though we don't need to store the whole file in the local machine. The download/upload of the local machine can still be a bottleneck if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able you can use Cloudinary as an alternative to S3.  They support remote upload via URL and more.

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_examples