# Is the S3 "US Standard" region the same as "us-east-1" in EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am planning on running a script located on an EC2 instance in **us-east-1d**.

The script basically pulls in images from a few different places and will throw them into an S3 bucket in the **US-Standard Region.**

Since there is no way to upload directly into an s3 bucket (by sending an API request that causes S3 to fetch a file from a remote URL [as written about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586533/is-it-possible-to-upload-to-s3-directly-from-url-using-post) and I don't think this has changed) I would like to make sure that the each image I save as temp file on my ec2 will not result in additional bandwidth charges when written to S3 (ie. leaves the Amazon data center).  Will a **us-east-1d** EC2 instance uploading to a **US-Standard S3 bucket** will be communicating within the same AWS region?

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated as it will be terabytes of data and I'm on a shoestring bucket I'd like to know before proceeding.

Comment: Re: your shoestring budget: [turn on detailed billing and set up cloudwatch monitoring for your billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html) -- AWS obviously is in business to make money, but they don't want or need to do it by sticking people with unexpected charges, so they have made it pretty easy to avoid surprises.  You can view graphs of your approximate charges-to-date and even set alarms if your accrued charges exceed thresholds you define.  Data transfer has its own metrics.

Comment: Totally agreed with @Michael-sqlbot here. CloudWatch alarms are awesome for avoiding unexpected costs, such as for resources you forgot you created.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

"US Standard" means "us-east-1".

According to [S3 Pricing FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)

> There is no Data Transfer charge for data transferred between Amazon
>   EC2 and Amazon S3 within the same Region or for data transferred
>   between the Amazon EC2 Northern Virginia Region and the Amazon S3 US
>   Standard Region.

This will mean that if your instance is in any of the **us-east-1** AZs and your bucket is in the **US Standard** region, any movement of data between the 2 should cost nothing.

Also, depending on your use case, you may want to look at the new [AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforbrowser/) as it may offer the direct to S3 uploads you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a table from Amazon captured December 2016 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-region.html). There is a vast set of more detailed endpoint mappings here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html.

[image: Amazon service region cross reference]

Comment: I dont know why amazon doesn't just put the region code next to the name

Answer (score 4):

US standard includes us-east and part of us-west (oregon). It's a legacy construct that only applies for S3

Comment: Actually, the US Standard region is its own region: `us-east-1`. (source: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/276#issuecomment-43145369)

Comment: That's correct, but what I was trying to say is that us-east-1 (S3 "standard") uses data center facilities in both Virginia and Oregon. It's a really weird duck in the AWS service family & the only service I know of that lets me spin up resources in two regions. I can even specify just the Virginia region with s3-external-1.amazonaws.com (Northern Virginia only). http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html (browse down to S3)

Comment: This used to be true, but seems true no longer.  I can't find anything by googling about where the data lives being changed, just about the "rename" of `us-standard` to `us-east-1`, which is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Just to keep it really clear, from official AWS S3 FAQ: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

> Q. Wasn’t there a US Standard region?
>
> We renamed the US Standard Region to US East (Northern Virginia)
>   Region to be consistent with AWS regional naming conventions. There is
>   no change to the endpoint and you do not need to make any changes to
>   your application.

So yes, `us-east-1` is the same.