# RedShift COPY Command on Sub-set of Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run the COPY command to copy a sub-set of my s3 bucket's objects into Redshift.

```
copy my_table
FROM 's3://my_bucket/1234*'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<REMOVED>;aws_secret_access_key=<REMOVED>’ 
json 's3://my_bucket/json_path.json'
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Problem reading manifest file - S3ServiceException:The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint

I looked up this error "... using the specified endpoint" - the AWS [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/s3serviceexception-error.html) say to put the bucket + redshift in the same region.

My S3 bucket is located in US Standard. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21008950/409976), "US Standard" equates to `us-east-1`.

And the Redshift cluster's region is `us-east-1a`.

Although I'm not sure of the cause of this problem, I'm curious if I need to use a [manifest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html) rather than only copy s3 bucket objects (from `my_bucket`) that begin with `1234`.

What's my issue here?

Comment: can you try copying specific file using same command that you are firing         copy my_table
FROM 's3://my_bucket/1234_filename'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<REMOVED>;aws_secret_access_key=<REMOVED>’ 
json 's3://my_bucket/json_path.json'

Comment: Sandesh - I tried that out. But got `ERROR: Problem reading manifest file - S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403`. But, if I try to run `COPY` against the entire bucket, it just sits for ~5 minutes (still executing), but I kill it since it's not manageable for what I want to do - periodically run the `COPY` and then query against the data.

Comment: check for named end point. some details here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/managing-data-consistency.html